# How to get data from array object in WordPress plugin api

Tags: wordpress

```
 http://localhost/wordpress/give-api/forms/?key=15443f18029e6f5d3b65d04e1640ffbe&token=c3de770a410282359413c74a588c5c74
```

The above link is a plugin api link. Above link won't work to your browser.
when I set the above link in the browser , it returns array object like http://postimg.org/image/6ozmjy0e7/ .
My question is , how can I set this url in a variable in wordpress and how can I get the data from that array object. I just want to get the data from that array object. If any other process is available, then please suggest me. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functions.php:

```
function displayApiUrl() {
    global $apiUrl; // you probably don't actually need to set it global as it is a function
    $apiUrl = 'http://localhost/wordpress/give-api/forms/?key=15443f18029e6f5d3b65d04e1640ffbe&token=c3de770a410282359413c74a588c5c74';
    return $apiUrl;
}
```

In your theme you can now use:

```
<?php $api = displayApiUrl(); ?>
```

With that you can process your array in a foreach loop:

```
<?php
$json_url = file_get_contents($api); 
$json_data = json_decode($json_url, true); 

foreach ($json_data['forms'] as $form) { 
    $form_id = $form['info']['id']; 
    echo $form_id; 
}
?>
```

Comment: `$api = displayApiUrl();
foreach ($api as $api_value) {
    echo esc_html($api_value->info['id']);
}` ** I write this way but it say invalid argument **

Comment: What happens wen you do: foreach ($api as $value) { print_r($value['forms']['info']); }

Comment: **My code is in the 15 line. It returns** `http://localhost/wordpress/give-api/forms/?key=15443f18029e6f5d3b65d04e1640ffbe&token=c3de770a410282359413c74a588c5c74
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\mycpt.php on line 15
Array ( )`

Comment: Mmh. I replaced echo with return in my answer. Please try.

Comment: **Same case Bro** ...  `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\mycpt.php on line 15
Array ( )`

Comment: Okay, it is not an array what you have, but a JSON file. Try: var_dump(json_decode($api)); If that works, you need to json_decode before your foreach

Comment: **When I write** `$api = displayApiUrl();
var_dump(json_decode($api));
echo '<hr>';` **this retrun null, I also hope this is json. But how can I json_decode before the foreach loop.If you help me, I can do it. Thanks.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92643/discussion-between-andyderuyter-and-anam-hossain).

Answer (score 0):

The new "standard" for WordPress rest apis is Json Rest API, which will be partially integrated into WordPress core in the next release.

You can get it here https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ and documentation at http://wp-api.org/

In terms of the question how to put array information into the URL, the format is

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/endpoint?array_1[key1]=Pensacola&array_1[key2]=Florida
```

The URL of course changes, and the wp-json/endpoint is replaced with whatever the final endpoint is for which ever rest api you choose to use.